# Hacer que un led se encuenda cada vez más rapido y otro cada vez más lento

Tags: arduino

No tengo mucha idea de arduino y estoy intentando hacer lo del título:

```
void setup (){
{
 int i = 0;
 pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);//nos aseguramos que esta apagado
}
}
void loop(){
  for(int j=1500;j>100;j=j-100);
 {
  digitalWrite (i, LOW);
  delay(j);
  digitalWrite (i, HIGH);
  delay(j);
 }
 for(int j=100;j<1500;j=j+100);{
  digitalWrite (i, LOW);
  delay(j);
  digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  delay(j);
 }

}
```

tengo que hacer que la led 
vaya apagandose mas rapido 
hasta llegar a 100 microsegundos 
y después que vuelva a su tiempo de antes
osea de 100 a 1500 microsegundos el pin 13
utilizando el for
osea tengo que asignar un tiempo “j=x tiempo”
o algo asi y despues restarlo al tiempo creo.

> Posible solución?

```
void setup (){
    {
     pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(13, LOW);//nos aseguramos que esta apagado
    }
    }
    void loop(){
      for(int j=1500;j>100;j=j-100);
     {
      digitalWrite (13, LOW);
      delay(j);
      digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
      delay(j);
     }
     for(int j=100;j<1500;j=j+100);{
      digitalWrite (13, LOW);
      delay(j);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(j);
     }

    }
```

No funciona:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo veo correcto. Lo único que tienes que cambiar es la asignación del pin, es decir, el PIN i es el 13, para luego en los bucles escribir sobre el pin 13

```
void setup (){
{
 int i = 13; // Definimos el valor 13.
 int j = 0;  // Definimos la variable del tiempo.
 pinMode (i, OUTPUT);  // Indicamos que el pin es de salida es el 13
 digitalWrite(i, LOW); // Apagamos el LED al poner el pin 13 en estado bajo.
}
```

Comment: Es decir que no hace falta la `i` en los bucles? Podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como tiene que quedar? Soy bastante noob en esto.

Comment: La función `digitalWrite` requiere de dos parámetros: el pin asociado, y el estado que quieres poner a dicho pin. En tu código estás indicando que se encienda el pin `i`, que es el 0. @Jose te indica que lo cambies para que se encienda el 13 y no el 0

Comment: he editado la pregunta con el codigo que segñun he comprendido es correcto, es así?

Comment: Como lo has editado es correcto, pero no se hace así. Se hace normalmente como yo te indiqué, si no, no tiene sentido crear una variable.  La variable i, le das el valor 13 (El pinout del arduino) pero si te interesa cambiarlo al 10, por ejemplo, pues le das valor 10 a la variable i, en lugar del 13 y habrás cambiado el pin de conexión, sin tener que cambiar todo el programa. Por eso te comenté que lo tenías todo correctamente, solo tenías que asignar el 13 a la i, y el  pinMode (i, OUTPUT), digitalWrite(i, LOW);

Comment: Acabo de reeditar la respuesta incluyendo la variable de tiempo.